# Does this circuit use a N-channel MOSFET properly?

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet

I am building a circuit that uses a SPDT switch to turn on/off a power MOSFET. The MOSFET is used to cut the main power of the circuit, as it draws more current than the utilized switch. Below is the circuit I have so far: [image]

The circuit in the box 'Circuit in question' is from: [MOSFET as a switch](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html)

Also, here is the link to the datasheet of the MOSFET: [IRF3205 Datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF3205-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355def244190a)

I also have a couple of smaller questions:

1. What is the purpose of the flyback diode?
2. Is the IRF3205 in enhancement mode?
3. Where do I calculate the resistors? I have read the datasheet, and did not find any mention of such calculations, unless I missed them.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

The load is apparently some inductive device, probably a relay or motor that is being modeled as a resistance with what appears to be an indicator diode. The flyback diode is there to provide a path for current to take when power is removed from the load; the energy stored in the magnetic field of the relay's coil or motor's winding has to go somewhere and without the diode, it will choose its own path, possibly not a convenient one for you.

The MOSFET is an enhancement-mode device, as shown by the broken line between source and drain. The channel is "enhanced" when the gate voltage rises above the source voltage by at least the threshold voltage. Very slightly at first, but reaching usable levels with increasing Vgs.

R5 controls how quickly the gate charges up and therefore how quickly the MOSFET "turns on". The gate can be modeled as a capacitor to the source and usually you want a bit of resistance between it and whatever is driving it to limit how much current flows. This application doesn't look especially critical (not switching at high frequency), so I'd try 200 or so ohms and see how things shake out.

R6 pulls the gate voltage down to ground to turn the MOSFET off. The gate is insulated from the rest of the device by an oxide layer (Metal-OXIDE-Semiconductor), and open-circuiting it like you do when you flip the power switch can leave charge "stranded" on the gate and keep the channel enhanced - the MOSFET will continue to conduct. The pulldown resistor bleeds this charge off. Exact values aren't important - 10k is a popular choice. Just make sure it isn't so small that the voltage divider it forms with R5 doesn't reduce the gate voltage too much. Or move it to the other side of R5 where it's not an issue. Edit: OR OR, as @MOSFET mentions, keep it in the voltage divider configuration if you need it to keep the Vgs below the max rating.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It appears the circuit is using the N-channel MOSFET correctly. It's acting as a switch.

> What is the purpose of the flyback diode?

It's needed for inductive loads. It provides a current path for the inductive current when the MOSFET is turned off rapidly. Without it, a large voltage develops across the load that will be seen by the MOSFET. That diode may be optional depending on your application but useful to just leave it there anyway as it does no harm.

> Is the IRF3205 in enhancement mode?

Yes. It's the "normally open" version of MOSFETs.

> Where do I calculate the resistors? I have read the datasheet, and did not find any mention of such calculations, unless I missed them.

You likely never will find the values of those resistors in datasheets as every application is different (with the exception that the datasheet happens to include a reference design circuit that just so happens to coincide with your application).

Depending on the voltage on J1 pin 1 or SW5 terminal 3 (same thing) and the fact that SW5 terminal 1 is grounded, you may not even need those resistors provided the voltage from J1 pin 1 is less than the max Vgs of the MOSFET (usually 20V but you can find that in the datasheet).R5 and R6 sets up a voltage divider for if the J1 voltage is greater than Vgs max. The idea is that R5 and R6 scale down a high voltage to an appropriate voltage for the MOSFET gate. A good voltage for Vgs should be around 10V-15V. see "resistor divider" for more information on the calculation. There are online calculators if you don't like math: https://www.ti.com/download/kbase/volt/volt_div3.htm

Answer (score 1):

> *What is the purpose of the flyback diode?*

You should properly read the article you linked: -

[image]

So, in your circuit there is no apparent purpose.

> *Is the IRF3205 in enhancement mode?*

Figure 1 in the data sheet shows that it is an enhancement type MOSFET: -

[image]

Additionally, the MOSFET's symbol is that of an enhancement type device.

> *Where do I calculate the resistors? I have read the datasheet, and did
> not find any mention of such calculations, unless I missed them.*

R6 is usually between 4k7 and 100 kΩ. R5 is usually around 10 Ω. The resistor in series with the LED has a value totally dependent on the LED and incoming power supply voltage so, I can't advise on that currently.